# passing arrays or ranges to VBA udf

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am trying to pass an array to a UDF to avoid massive duplication of code. As a simple example:

```
    function USERFUNC1(inp as variant)
    Dim array_size As Integer
    dim i as integer
    dim values as double
    array_size = WorksheetFunction.CountA(inp)

    for i = 1 to array_size
              values = values + inp(i)
    Next i
              USERFUNC1 = values
    End function


    function USERFUNC2(input1 as variant, input2 as variant)
    Dim array_size As Integer
    dim i as integer
    dim values as double
    array_size = WorksheetFunction.CountA(input1)
    redim nested_array(array_size)

    for i = 1 to array_size
              nested_array(i) = input1(i)+input2(i)
    Next i

              USERFUNC2= USERFUNC1(nested_array)
    End function
```

In the example I have create I have the nested array that I am passing internally to the UDF. However when run this results in a by ref error. I am sure that this can be done but I appear to be missing something

**EDIT**

It seems what I wrote caused confusion, essentially I have a number of functions, the above is just to demonstrate the idea.

On some of the cells I am calculating a value using a function (call it fugacity) that picks up values into an array a range from the worksheet. In another function (phase equilibrium) I need to perform the same calculation (fugacity) within the second function  (phase equilibrium) using values calculated within the second function. This requires me to pass the array from the second function into the first or write out the entire first function again within the second.

I could do that however it make the 2nd function much more difficult to debug as I can no longer be certain that the nested calculation is performing the right calculation, rather I need to check the whole thing. So far I have about 250 lines of code in the first and 300 line the second and within the second (phase equilibrium) I need to perform the first (fugacity) 4 times.

Comment: Arrays are zero-based by default so you will get an error when i>array_size-1.  Also, use UBound(inp) to get the size.

Comment: Do you want to pass an array or a range? My understanding from your question is that you want to pass an array...

Comment: You're going to get all kinds of errors with what you have written. And how to treat the arguments of the functions will differ depend on whether you are passing an array or a range, as well as the number of values.  I do not find it possible to reproduce your problem with the information you have provided. Please read the help topics on how to ask a good question, and also about producing a minimal but complete and verifiable example.

Answer (score 1):

If you want USERFUNC1 to return an array of the values in the inp range, then merely:

```
function USERFUNC1(inp as Range) as Variant
    USERFUNC1 = inp
End function
```

This will be a 1-based two dimensional array where the first dimension represents the rows, and the second dimension the columns in the original range inp.

I'm not sure what your end goal is, but you may not even need USERFUNC1

Comment: Hi Ron,Thanks for your reply. The example I have shown is VERY simple compared to what I am writing. This is an engineering application where I am calculating some intermediate values and passing them on to the main function.

Comment: @user2978403 The fact remains that if your goal is to place a range into an array, it is as simple as array = range.  You can then process the array in your VBA routines (and much more quickly than going back and forth to the worksheet). If the ranges are not contiguous, you might need to use multiple arrays (one for each area), but that's pretty simple also.